# stuck in a infinite do while loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, do-while

I am trying to make a simple guess my number game in c++ but the computer need to guess my number. But the problem is that I am stuck in this infinite loop. I am just a beginner so it's a really basic program.

This is my code:

```
int secretNumber = rand() %100 + 1; // random number between 1-100
int tries=0;
int input;

cout <<"typ your number\n";
cin >> input;

do
{
    cout <<secretNumber <<endl;
    ++tries;

    if (secretNumber > input)
    {
        cout <<"To high i guess?\n";
    }
    else if (secretNumber < input)
    {
        cout <<"To low I guess?\n";
    }
    else 
    {
        cout <<"Yes, i got it in " <<tries <<" tries!";
    }
}while (input != secretNumber);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You're only getting one number from the user, then you're comparing it again and again in your loop. You probably should prompt the user for a number within the loop instead.

Comment: Computer needs to guess your number?.... Maybe it's you who needs to guess computer's number? I'm confused, and so are the answerers, it seems...

Comment: @user1096188 well i already made a program where i need to guess the random number of the computer. now i wanted to challenge myself and see if i could make it the other way around, turned out i can't

Comment: I think you would benefit from describing the problem in english in more detail first, especially which parts of the program you want to repeat, and until when

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the computer is only guessing (by random) once when the program starts, but should guess each time the loop is iterated. you should move the random number generation inside the loop:

```
int secretNumber = 0;
int tries=0;
int input;

cout <<"typ your number\n";
cin >> input;

do
{
    /* the fix is here */
    secretNumber = rand() %100 + 1; // random number between 1-100
    cout <<secretNumber <<endl;
    ++tries;

    if (secretNumber > input)
    {
        cout <<"To high i guess?\n";
    }
    else if (secretNumber < input)
    {
        cout <<"To low I guess?\n";
    }
    else 
    {
        cout <<"Yes, i got it in " <<tries <<" tries!";
    }
}while (input != secretNumber);

return 0;
```

Comment: thanks man this helped me, it olny takes the computer a long time to guess the number so i think i wil change the range in 1-20 instead of 1-100. thanks allot dude.

Comment: you can improve this by dynamically setting a lower and upper bound in each iteration, after the computer knows if he guessed too high or too low. then finally it will meet in the middle. also, instead of guessing random, there are statistical approaches that improves the computers guessing capabilities a lot. (like: start with 100, if too high, try half value next time.. and so on)

Comment: i posted a question and 5min later i learned so much and you are responsible for that, i can't thank you enough

Answer (score 5):

place `cin >> input` into loop body

Comment: thanks it helped me for 90% so far the problem now is that it always says the same number and it needs to guess is, can you help me with that? thanks for what you did so far :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you should move the random number generation inside the loop.

Comment: +1 the first answer that takes in account that the computer should guess the number

Answer (score 3):

The value of the variable `input` is never changed in the loop, so the terminating condition `input != secretNumber` is never met.

You should take the input inside the loop. So write `cin >> input` at the beginning of the loop.

**Edit:**

If the computer should guess, then still the value of `input` needs to be changed in the loop, which is not present in your code. The loop runs with the same value in `input` every time.

To make you computer make a guess, you should follow some scheme. The computer may draw the numbers at random - which you can get through moving `secretNumber = rand()%100 + 1` inside the loop. But this approach may not perform good, the loop may still run for a very long time. This is shown in @Kaii's answer.

A more efficient approach is the [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Number_guessing_game). In this case you should keep track of the guesses the computer makes. Keep two variables `high` and `low` which should store the guesses higher and lower than `input` respectively. Whenever a guess in higher than the number, store it in `high`, and store any guess lower than `input` in `low`. Then the computer should try its new guess between `high` and `low`. A random guess should be `secretNumber = low + rand() % (high - low)`. In worst case it will take as much as 100 iterations. For the best results, each guess should be `(high + low) / 2`. According to the conditions, one of `high` and `low` will be updated in each iteration. This approach will ensure that the computer will guess the correct number within 7 guesses.

In your code it should be like this:

```
int secretNumber = rand() % 100 + 1; // random number between 1-100
int tries=0;
int input;
int low = 1, high = 100;

cout <<"typ your number\n";
cin >> input;

do
{
    secretNumber = (high + low) / 2;
    cout << secretNumber <<endl;
    ++tries;

    if (secretNumber > input)
    {
        cout << "Too high I guess?\n";
        high = secretNumber;
    }

    else if (secretNumber < input)
    {
        cout << "Too low I guess?\n";
        low = secretNumber;
    }

    else 
    {
        cout << "Yes, i got it in " << tries << " tries!";
    }        
} while (input != secretNumber);

return 0;
```

Comment: @Stijn to be fair: this one is the most correct answer i think. But thanks for the acceptance ;)

Comment: @Kaii i am just being honnest about which answer helped me the most :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the input within the loop. Right now you prompt for a value BEFORE you start looping, then never ask the user for another number. If the guess can't be changed, the loop can never exit.

changing to

```
do {
    cin >> input;
```

will solve the infinite loop.

Comment: the computer should guess, not the user.

Comment: @Kaii: and the computer can type a number on the keyboard... how?

Comment: the computer can guess a random number by `secretNumber = rand() %100 + 1;`, read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

infinite loop in your code because the argument for while always true until you get the true number.

you need to add another argument. example you want set maximal tries to 5 times. then it will be like this

```
do{
    //do your stuff here
}while((input != secretNumber)&&(tries<=5))
```

when you input wrong number for 5 times, the application will finish

Comment: it will always fail, but at least stop failing after 5 iterations.

Comment: actually the true answer is chiphor's,Marc's , and triclosan's answer. i'm not read carefully >.<, i'm sorry :)

Comment: then read again, because triclosan and marc are wrong, too ;-)

Comment: really? :D.  i was though it's true. is it not solve the infinite loop problem?

Comment: the exercise is "solve the infinite loop AND fulfil the requirements". the requirements are: "the computer need to guess my number". Effectively `cin >> input` inside the loop lets the user guess the computers number.. but it should be the other way round. Correct answers are provided by FlopCoder, chiphor and me. you'll realize when you carefully read the comments of the OP.

Comment: ouw, i get it, "the computer need to guess my number".. :( thank you very much